# Facebook Open Graph Actions And Objects Confusion

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

I am having trouble creating actions and objects for my game.

1. I click the "Create New Object Type" button.
2. I add an object type, we'll call it "Recipe".
3. I click "Create New Action Type" button.
4. I try to create "Cook" Action Type.
5. I type "recipe" in the "Connected Object Types"
6. I receive the following error message:

The specified action type is invalid because you need to supply at least one connected object. Please add at least one connected object before proceeding.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There should be a typeahead search in the 'Connected Object Types' box, it won't accept plain text, if the typeahead isn't working you may be encountering a bug

Comment: The typeahead thing wasn't working yesterday for whatever reason...its working today. Thanks.